# what software & How to Synchronize sequence pictures with audio and make it a video just like gif image

Tags: audio, software, sync

I recently went on vacation with my family, and while capturing pictures I took some in sequence like in burst mode, for example, I took 4 pictures while the person turned his head from left to right. When I view then in sequence it looks like stop motion.

The real question is, how can I make use of those expressions of the person and synchronize it to music, it should look like he is shaking his head back and forth  reacting to the music.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pretty much any movie editor that allows the import of single frames.

First line up your audio, work out where you want the key frames to be (eg for reversing the movement when shaking the head) and then fill in the other frames.

If your editor allows interpolation between frames, then you can use this to make the movie less jerky.

Or you can use one of the free online gif creators to join your images into a gif and then import that into a video editor - slightly more effort, but not much.

Comment: holy crap, you do NOT want to put your photos through GIF before using them.  GIF only allows 256 colors, using a 256 entry palette of 24bit RGB colors.  This is why gradients in GIFs of real photos look so terrible.

Comment: Peter - the OP asks how to do gif. Also. It is perfect for some uses.

Comment: He asked how to do something LIKE a gif, just to give the idea of the kind of animation loop he was looking for.  Since webm isn't widely supported yet, and HTML5 video is overkill for very short loops, GIF is still the widely used format for such animations.  That doesn't mean it isn't terrible quality!

Comment: Point being, yes if you want to publish as a GIF, then make one (e.g. with `ffmpeg -i %d.jpg  output.gif`).  Otherwise it's a horrible choice for making your image frames into a video that you can import.  (lossless h.264, huffyuv, or utvideo would be good choices, if your editor can't be fed a directory-of-images directly)